# Authentication Support with AWS failing to send

Tags: 7, emails

I am trying to fix our SMTP Drupal 7 configuration because I am now getting errors that its unable to send the email. I am using AWS as our SMTP server and I can send a test email from that just fine. I regenerated my SMTP credentials and updated the Drupal SMTP module configuration with that to see if that was the issue but its still erroring sending the email. I've posted pictures below.

I'ved checked to see if the PHP mail() function works, but that just returns false and I never get an email from that either. From what I've read, using SMTP bypasses the mail() function so that shouldn't be causing an issue. I believe mail() may be disabled by our server host.

Unfortunately I don't have sudo to our webbox so I'm going to ask my web host to send me the the apache logs and maillog. Is there any other log files that might be

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

Edit I have since created a fresh install of Drupal on my own webbox and installed only the SMTP module. From this my AWS email still failed to send, and I'm assuming thats because I cannot verify my domain (Student run site hosted as a subdomain to our institution so I cannot modify our DNS). Instead I figured I'd try setting up a gmail account, which I got working on my fresh install. After copying those same settings to my production environment it still refuses to send. I tried updating the SMTP module because it was a few versions behind but that didnt help. Interesting to note that my fresh install provides way more debug output.

[image]